# Getting empty string while trying to read first byte of bitcoin block

Tags: python, bitcoin

I've downloaded a block named blk00000.dat from https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe/blob/master/test/btc200/blocks/blk00000.dat

I've written the following code to read first byte of the file but I am getting an empty sting. What's that I am doing wrong?

```
f = open('blk00000.dat')
byte1 = f.read(1)
print byte1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the first byte is not a printable character. Since you are reading binary data, you need to open the file in binary mode:

```
f = open('blk00000.dat', 'rb')
```